# How do I specify a Chef attribute that applies to a cluster?

Tags: chef

Chef has a concept of environment attributes that applies to all hosts within an environment. It also has a concept of attributes that are specific to a single node. But is there a way to specify an attribute that applies to a cluster of nodes?

For example, let's say I have "host1" and "host2" which collectively make up the logical node "host" furthermore they are in environment "joe" which contains all of the hosts that are provision for the client joe. How do I specify attributes that apply to host1 and host2, but not the rest of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using roles? You can add as many roles as you want to a machine, and you can pass runlists and attributes via roles, so you could have your 2 hosts within that role that has the attributes that you need.

Role can also override attributes just in case they are assigned somewhere else. Please see the following graph for attribute assignation order (Higher number wins) :

[image]

And here is the full [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) regarding attributes